# How to increment id's on Input fields with Jquery on clone

Tags: jquery

I am trying to increment a form field ID so they are all different when i click on the plus to create a new row of input fields.

Here is my code so far

```
//Order Form
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#ordertable tbody>tr:last');
        $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last #prodcode').val('');
        $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last #meterage').val('');
        $('td.imgsample:last a').remove();
        return false;
    });
```

On the first line within the click function how can i change the input fields (prodcode & meterage) to be prodcode1 meterage1 e.t.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are going to do this more often then once.

```
//Somewhere global
var counter = 0;
//Order Form
$("#add").click(function() {
    counter++;
    var cln = $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
    cln.find("[id^='prodcode'], [id^='meterage']").each(function(i, val) {
        val.id = val.id.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
    });
    cln.insertAfter('#ordertable tbody>tr:last');
    $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last #prodcode').val('');
    $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last #meterage').val('');
    $('td.imgsample:last a').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Of course there are "cleaner" solutions without using a global counter

For the problem mentioned in the first comment something along the lines of

```
$("tr [id^='prodcode'], tr [id^='meterage']").live("blur", function() {
    ....
    $(this).val() //instead of $("#prodcode").val()
    ....
});
```

should do

Comment: How can i work this in with the id created?  Before it was running this script perfectly.  Now i need the #prodcode to carry through the id
$("#prodcode").blur(function() {
 $.post(
    'public/themes/lbd/js/searchimage.php', //this page reads the image code and gives you the image location
    { action: 'searchimage', imgreference: $('#prodcode').val() },
    function(data) { 
     //export the link as data            
     $("td.imgsample").html(data);
    }
   );
 });

Comment: The code above Jitter actually prints 0 and 1 for every additional row, it doesnt increment anymore than that?

Comment: You should rename the `i` in `.each(function(i, val) {` to get the desired result.

Comment: The 0 and 1 and then no increment issue was as Nick Craver pointed out a naming issue I had to vars with name i

Comment: Updated my post with code that should work now. As you want to clone the last tr the cln.find(..) got a bit more complex

Comment: Thats wicked mate, thank you!  However the values dont clear because they are looking for the wrong ID's

Comment: I guess you need to change your event handlers a bit. Check updated post maybe that gets you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ordertable tbody>tr:last #prodcode')
.val('')
.attr(
  'id', function(i,id) {
         match = id.match(/\d+?$/);
         if ( match.length ) { match++; return 'prodcode' + match } // could be match[0], may return array!
         else return id + 1 // or '2' if you wish
        }
);
```

same for next element.

Comment: This doesnt increment anything unfortunately :(